# ¿Cómo cargar múltiples página previo aún loading usando jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5

Estoy implementando una lista de opciones múltiples, mi idea es poder cargar contenidos o páginas dinámicamente sin que se recargue la página a través de un `iframe`.

Todo parece funcionar bien, al ejecutarlo se puede ver que carga el primer sitio, pero el **loading** permanece activo, es decir, no desaparece al cargar el sitio.

Por otro lado, en el listado de los sitios a cargar en el `iframe` no funcionan como el primer sitio.

Me pueden explicar que configuraciones debo realizar en el código

**Mi código**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var vid = $('#myvid');

 //default video source
    $(vid).attr("src", $("a.link:first").attr("href"));

    // addClass playing to first video link
    $("a.link:first").addClass("playing");


$("a.link").on("click" , function  (event) {

 // prevent link default
    event.preventDefault();
 
    // change video source
    $(vid).attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));

    // remouve class playing from unplayed video href
    $(".vids a").removeClass("playing");

    // add class playing to video href
    $(this).addClass("playing");

    // add class paused to give the play/pause button the right look  
    $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
    
    
    // play the video
    vid[0].play();
   
});


//VIDEO EVENTS
    //video canplay event
    vid.on('canplay', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
    });
    
    //video waiting for more data event
    vid.on('waiting', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    });
//end
});
```

```css
.container * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container *:after , .container *:before {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #A97A7A;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #010101;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 460px;
}
.vidcontainer {

 width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 405px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.videolist {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.vids {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #292626;
    max-height: 450px;
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #616060;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    direction: rtl;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #8A8A8A;
    border: 1px solid #AFACAC;

}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #FF8D00;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#fff;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
background-color:#ccc;
}


.vids a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

/*--- controllers ---*/
.controllers {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.controllers button {
    border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #777;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.controllers button:focus {
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
    border-color: #ff8d00;
    color: #ff8d00;
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.btnPlay:after {
    content: "\f04b";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.paused:after {
    content: "\f04c";
}

.sound:after {
content: "\f027";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.sound2:after {
content: "\f028";
}

.muted:after {
    content: "\f026";
}
.btnFS:after {
     content: "\f065";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.ads {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #777;
    top: 27.5px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 11;
}
.bigplay {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 127.5px;
    left: 85px;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}
.closeme {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    color: #ff8d00;
    font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
 }
.playing:after {
    content: "\f01d";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ff8d00;
    float: left;
}
/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */

.topControl {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Progress bar */
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #999;
}
.progress span {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.timeBar{
    z-index:10;
    width:0;
    background: #ff8d00;
}

.bufferBar{
    z-index:5;
    width:0;
    background: #eee;
}
/* time and duration */
.time{
    width:12%;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:12px;
    right: -12%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.topControl:hover .time {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}


.topControl:hover .progress {
    width: 88%;
    height: 12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.volumeBar{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff8d00;
    z-index: 10;
}

.loading {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,141,0,0.5);
    height: 405px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
    top: 172.5px;
    left: 330px;
    position: absolute;
}
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}


ul.speedcnt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
}

ul.speedcnt li {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', tahoma , serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

ul.speedcnt li.selected {
    background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="vidcontainer">
<iframe id="myvid" >

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  
</iframe>


<div class="loading">
 <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>
    </div>

 <div class="videolist">
  <nav class="vids">
<a class="link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">test1</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns">test2</a>

   <a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">test3</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://futbolworldcup.com/">test4</a>

   <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test5</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test6</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test7</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test8</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">tsest9</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nota como el iframe tiene la propiedad `onload="ocultarLoad();"` y agregué la funcion `ocultarLoad()` en el JS. Además de eso en el `$("a.link").on("click",...)` agregué una linea donde vuelve a mostrar tu overlay de cargando cada vez que lo presiona.

---

**Importante**: Por mera conveniencia moví la carga de tu JS a **antes** de tu html. Si no haces eso aparecerá un mensaje de que no existe el método `ocultarLoad()`. Luego puedes agregarle el `$("iframe").on("load",function(){...})` dentro de tu `$(document).ready()`. [Ejemplo en JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js6o94qv/), el snippet inluido en SO no funciona por eso mismo

```js
function ocultarLoad(){
 $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

 var vid = $('#myvid');

 //default video source
    $(vid).attr("src", $("a.link:first").attr("href"));

    // addClass playing to first video link
    $("a.link:first").addClass("playing");


$("a.link").on("click" , function  (event) {

 // prevent link default
    event.preventDefault();
 $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    // change video source
    $(vid).attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));

    // remouve class playing from unplayed video href
    $(".vids a").removeClass("playing");

    // add class playing to video href
    $(this).addClass("playing");

    // add class paused to give the play/pause button the right look  
    $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
    
    
    // play the video
    vid[0].play();
   
});


//VIDEO EVENTS
    //video canplay event
    vid.on('canplay', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
    });
    
    //video waiting for more data event
    vid.on('waiting', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    });
//end
});
```

```css
.container * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.container *:after , .container *:before {
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2.title {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #A97A7A;
}
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #010101;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 460px;
}
.vidcontainer {

 width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 405px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.videolist {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: rgb(76, 76, 76);
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.vids {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #292626;
    max-height: 450px;
    min-height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid #616060;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    list-style: none;
    direction: rtl;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    background-color: #8A8A8A;
    border: 1px solid #AFACAC;

}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #FF8D00;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background-color:#fff;
}
.vids::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
background-color:#ccc;
}


.vids a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #616060;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

/*--- controllers ---*/
.controllers {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.controllers button {
    border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #777;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #4C4C4C;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.controllers button:focus {
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px #4C4C4C;
    border-color: #ff8d00;
    color: #ff8d00;
    background-color: #4C4C4C;
}

.btnPlay:after {
    content: "\f04b";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.paused:after {
    content: "\f04c";
}

.sound:after {
content: "\f027";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.sound2:after {
content: "\f028";
}

.muted:after {
    content: "\f026";
}
.btnFS:after {
     content: "\f065";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.ads {
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #777;
    top: 27.5px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 11;
}
.bigplay {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 127.5px;
    left: 85px;
    z-index: 11;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ff8d00;
}
.closeme {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px!important;
    color: #ff8d00;
    font-size: 25px!important;
}

.playing {
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #ff8d00!important;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
 }
.playing:after {
    content: "\f01d";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    color: #ff8d00;
    float: left;
}
/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */

.topControl {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Progress bar */
.progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #999;
}
.progress span {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.timeBar{
    z-index:10;
    width:0;
    background: #ff8d00;
}

.bufferBar{
    z-index:5;
    width:0;
    background: #eee;
}
/* time and duration */
.time{
    width:12%;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:12px;
    right: -12%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.topControl:hover .time {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}


.topControl:hover .progress {
    width: 88%;
    height: 12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.volumeBar{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff8d00;
    z-index: 10;
}

.loading {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255,141,0,0.5);
    height: 405px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000;
    top: 172.5px;
    left: 330px;
    position: absolute;
}
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #C2C2C2!important;
}


ul.speedcnt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0s;
    -o-transition: 0s;
    transition: 0s;
}

ul.speedcnt li {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', tahoma , serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.speedcnt li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

ul.speedcnt li.selected {
    background-color: rgba(255, 141, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="vidcontainer">
<iframe id="myvid" onload="ocultarLoad();" >

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  
</iframe>


<div class="loading">
 <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
</div>
    </div>

 <div class="videolist">
  <nav class="vids">
<a class="link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page">test1</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns">test2</a>

   <a class="link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">test3</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://futbolworldcup.com/">test4</a>

   <a class="link" href="https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">test5</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4">test6</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Other_Media/H264_test8_voiceclip_mp4_480x320.mp4">test7</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/dw11222.mp4">test8</a>

   <a class="link" href="http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/Media-Convert/Unsupported/test7.mp4">tsest9</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
</div>
```